# nodejs настроить middleware для маршрута express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Есть вот такое приложение на ноде, где используем express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const user = require('./routes/user').user;
const browser= require('./routes/browser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// CORS middleware
const allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    next();
}

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.use('/', user);
app.use('/', browser);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port)
});
```

И модульный обработчик маршрута browser:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(function (req, res, next) { 
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
});

router.post('/get-content', (req, res) => { 

});
```

А проблема заключается в том, что при обращении к маршруту, в консоль из middleware выводится сначала пустой объект, и  после вызова next(), этот же middleware срабатывает второй раз и в теле запроса уже есть информация, которую я отправил. Как можно понять такой эффект?

Ответ: первый запрос без тела это запрос "OPTIONS" или [CORS pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) и обработать его можно так:

```
// CORS middleware
const allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) { 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    //intercepts OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        //respond with 200
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

Или использовать https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors